# sklearn train_test_split on scipy sparse matrix gives wrong result

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a sparse matrix with shape (346679, 86).

```
<346679x86 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int8'>' with 470018 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

To train and evaluate my model, I need to split it into train and test sets respectively.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(sparse_matrix, test_size=0.2, random_state=11)
```

Once this is done, I find the x_train and x_test have changed i.e some entire rows are turned to 0. I have checked the occurrence of rows with zero non-zero values for the original matrix using the code below:

```
def get_zero_rows(sparse_matrix):
    sparse_matrix = sparse_matrix.tocsr()
    count = 0
    for index, each in enumerate(sparse_matrix):
        if each.getnnz() < 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

It returns 0 for the original matrix but non-zero value for the split matrices. I don't understand why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building from an example in the `train_test_split` docs:

```
In [895]: X, y = sparse.random(50,10,.2,'csr'), range(50)
In [896]: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
     ...: ...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
     ...:     
In [897]: X
Out[897]: 
<50x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [898]: X_train
Out[898]: 
<33x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 68 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [899]: X_test
Out[899]: 
<17x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 32 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

No change in the total number of nonzeros

```
In [900]: np.count_nonzero(X.sum(1)==0)
Out[900]: 4
In [901]: np.count_nonzero(X_test.sum(1)==0)
Out[901]: 2
In [902]: np.count_nonzero(X_train.sum(1)==0)
Out[902]: 2
```

0 row sums also remain the same.

When I try the same with

```
X = (sparse.random(50,10,.2,'csr')*10).astype('int8')
```

0 row counts remain consistent, but I get fewer `nnz` elements.  Sparse math with `int8` might a problem.  Standard `int` or `float` dtypes might be safer.

`sparse` row indexing using matrix multiplication (with an `extractor` matrix), and I believe that is compiled for 32/64 bit dtypes.

---

The 'problem' I saw was an artifact of how I constructed the integer sparse matrix.  I had not properly `eliminated zeros`.

```
In [20]: from scipy import sparse
In [21]: M = sparse.random(100,10,.2,'csr')
In [22]: M
Out[22]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [23]: idx=np.arange(100)
In [24]: M[idx,:]
Out[24]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Make a random integer matrix by scaling the float one:

```
In [25]: M1 = (M*10).astype(int)
In [26]: M1
Out[26]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Indexing reduces the number of elements:

```
In [27]: M1[idx,:]
Out[27]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 183 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

But that's the same number that `count_nonzero` finds.  And what I get if I apply `elimnate_zeros`:

```
In [29]: M1.count_nonzero()
Out[29]: 183
In [30]: M1.eliminate_zeros()
In [31]: M1
Out[31]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 183 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [32]: M1[idx,:]
Out[32]: 
<100x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 183 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

With this scaling constructor, float values like 0.04 become 0, but aren't pruned from the sparsity until we explicitly do so.

Comment: I tried with standard int and the issue persisted, but when I tried with float, the issue is resolved. Should check why this is happening?

Comment: My integer matrix construction is at fault - I needed to `eleminate_zeros`.